# How to use '^@' in Vim scripts?

Tags: special-characters, vim

I'm trying to work around a problem with using ^@ (i.e., `<ctrl-@>`) characters in Vim scripts.  I can insert them into a script, but when the script runs it seems the line is truncated at the point where a ^@ was located.

My kludgy solution so far is to have a ^@ stored in a variable, then reference the variable in the script whenever I would have quoted a literal ^@. Can someone tell me what's going on here?  Is there a better way around this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is one reason why I never use raw special character values in scripts. While `^@` does not work, string `<C-@>` in mappings works as expected, so you may use one of

```
nnoremap <C-@> {rhs}
nnoremap <Nul> {rhs}
```

It is strange, but you cannot use `<Char-0x0>` here. Some notes about null byte in strings:

1. Inserting null byte into string truncates it: vim uses old C-style strigs that end with null byte, thus it cannot appear in strings. These strings are very inefficient, so if you want to generate a very large text, try accumulating it into a list of lines (using `setline` is very fast as buffer is represented as a list of lines).
2. Most functions that return list of strings (like `readfile`, `getline(start, end)`) or take list of strings (like `writefile`, `setline`, `append`) treat `\n` (NL) as Null. It is also the internal representation of buffer lines, see `:h NL-used-for-Nul`.
3. If you try to insert `\n` character into the command-line, you will get Null shown (but this is really a newline). If you want to edit a file that has `\n` in a filename (it is possible on *nix), you will need to prepend newline with backslash.

Comment: I'm trying to grab output that's going to the message buffer using `redirect =>>` to a variable.  When I capture output generated by an embedded `python` command the redirected text has ^@ characters, it seems as line endings.  I need some way to substitute actual line endings in for those chars.  Only way I've found is to grab the first character of the redirected text, which seems also always to be a ^@, into a variable.  Then I can reference that variable in substitute command.  I assume there's a more reliable way of stuffing ^@ value into a variable:  e.g., `let myvar = 0x0`?

Comment: @Herbert Sitz. You cannot have null in the string variable. If you want to replace literal `^@` (two characters) with null, the only way how you can do it is to turn the whole string into a list of bytes (represented by integer values) ([Int]) and then perform manipulations on it. Or pass this string into python script, do replacement and never pass back to vim.

Comment: @Herbert Sitz If you are trying to parse python exceptions that were somewhere rethrown by vim script, then there `^@` shown by `throw` command is actually a newline: `throw` assumes that there are no newlines in exception message and shows newlines according to the `:h NL-used-for-Nul`. So, something like `substitute(string, '\^@', "\n", 'g')` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks, that substitute didn't quite do the trick for me. Could be I'm missing something, but strings seem to be stored with newlines as null characters.  So essentially it didn't replace anything, and when I append the substituted string into the buffer the ^@'s appear instead of new lines.  I did get around this by appending the string and then doing :s/^@/\r/g .  I could also convert the string into list with :let mylist=split(mystring,'^@').

Comment: I use this...   let result = substitute(str, "\n", "", 'g')

Answer (score 2):

The byte `ctrl-@` is also known as `'\0'`.  Many languages, programs, etc. use it as an "end of string" marker, so it's not surprising that vim gets confused there.  If you must use this byte in the middle of a script string, it sounds like your workaround is a decent one.